# configure: error: "libevent is too old - you need to install a newer version"

Tags: linux, fedora, kali-linux, configure, honeypot

I get `Honeyd` package from [github](https://github.com/DataSoft/Honeyd) and read instructions for installing it. I installed all dependencies, but when I try to `./configure`, I get this error:

```
configure: error: "libevent is too old - you need to install a newer version.  Check http://www.monkey.org/~provos/libevent/"
```

I try in Kali linux and Fedora. Also I updated my libevent to final version from [libevent website](http://libevent.org/). But this error so remains.

**Note**: I could install Honeyd on Kali, but recently I uninstalled it. Now I cannot install it and I get this error.

Comment: If you carefully look at `./configure` output, it should tell you which check it performs before failing. This should shed some light about the version of `libevent` you need to have installed on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried `./configure --with-libevent` (or `./configure --with-libevent=/usr`) and this solved my problem.